# Convert pandas column to a list in specific positions

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I have an excel sheet of numbers. These are my fixed possible readings. There are hundreds of them. I have this data of all possible readings, unfortunately not running numbers. The position is important if you read further.

Example sheet, position does not change:

```
         Readings
0        1111        
1        1234
2        1243
3        9999
4        1237
5        1412
 ...
999      8878
```

Now on mondays I have to take new readings, say 5 of them(more in fact but 5 for simplicity).

Pandas data frame:

```
       Taken
0     9999
1     9999
2     1237
3     8878
4     1412
```

I like to represent them as a list showing the number of occurances. X if it appears X times, 0 if not. So these 5 readings taken would then be:

[0,0,0,2,1,1,1,....0]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The last part about what you want is not clear @JT. How did you come with the expected result ?

Comment: It is something like a one hot. If u see my readings, 1st and 2nd ones are 9999. This corresponds to index 3 of my sheet. Hence my list [0,0,0,2...]. Likewise, reading 3 is 1237, corresponds to position 4 of my sheet. And hence [0,0,02,1,...]. thanks.

Comment: So you want to find out the number of occurrences of each elements in input data w.r.t. original data index. Correct ?

Comment: Sounds right. Number of occurances of each reading wrt my reference sheet. It must still show a  zero if no such reading is taken.

Comment: Also the elements in original data are unique? Each number in original sheet will occur only once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may be a good approach for your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Readings":[1111,1234,1243,9999,1237,1412,8878]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Taken":[9999,9999,1237,8878,1412]})

def checkOcurrance(val):
    count = 0
    try:
        count = df2["Taken"].value_counts()[val]
    except:
        pass
    return count

df1["Ocurrance"] = df1["Readings"].apply(checkOcurrance)
```

Then df1 would result in:

```
>>> df1
   Readings  Ocurrance
0      1111          0
1      1234          0
2      1243          0
3      9999          2
4      1237          1
5      1412          1
6      8878          1
```

And you can pass the column Ocurrance to list to finally get your list as follows:

```
out = df1["Ocurrance"].tolist()
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> out
[0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L]
```

Comment: Cedric actually can I have this another way round. I feel this is not very efficient.

Comment: Cedric actually can I have this another way round and to take into account a rolling window without running a for loop? I am thinking along the lines of 

    df1["Ocurrance"] = df['readings']. rolling(min_periods=3,  
                                   window=3).apply(check_occurance).tolist()        

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I quite not understand your question. The solution I provided is not using a for loop. Please consider to approve/upvote the question if you feel it helps for your question. Cheers.